# Outlook 2007 Multiple Meeting Request with multiple times

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, meeting-request

I know this can't be a unique issue.  In my company, we have 75+ employees that all need to attend a meeting.  It is impossible to get all 75+ employees together at one time so I would like to create a meeting request with the multiple times the meeting is going to be held.  Ideally, the employee would click a link to accept the meeting request at that time.

```
The 2nd Quarter meeting is next Friday.    
Select a time to attend and it will automatically be added to your calendar

         *10am
         *12pm
         *2pm
```

Is there anything out there that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by scheduling the multiple meetings as meetings (not appointments) with yourself. Then, save each as a file (use a descriptive name) and attach them to an email that you send to people. The accept/reject options will be available for people to use, and people can just accept (and thus add to their calendar) the one they'll be attending.

We do this all the time at my company for social events, so as to not automatically put it on people's calendars but still get RSVPs :-).

Comment: At first I didn't follow your instructions explicitly enough.  I realized you said to save the requests to a file and then attach.  When I did that, everything worked as it should.  I appreciate your time in answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the describe what you are trying to do?

http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-outlook/434618-outlook-2007-meeting-request-multiple-time-options.html

Comment: Yes Sir.  That describes what I am trying to do but seems that the meeting organizer won't get a response as to who is coming to which meeting?  Thanks for looking.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - - but figured out a work around.

(1) set up your mtgs (as others have said, in the title, use the date and time)
(2) Then, while in calendar view, right click on the mtg and select "forward" (but don't forward it - just leave that email message open)
(3) do that for EACH mtg - - leaving each "forward" email open.
(4) Create your main email.
(5) Now, for EACH "forward" email, the mtg should show as an ATTACHMENT.  Click and HOLD on the attachment and DRAG it into the BODY (not attachment line) of your NEW email message.
...you should be able to drag all of the attachments into the new email.
(6) tell the attendees to open the attachment that is the date/time that works for them, then they need to select "add to calendar" - - this will then provide them with the option to: (a) accept the mtg, (b) tentatively accept, or (c) just copy the mtg.

It is allowing me to track those who accepted or tentatively accepted.  I'm also receiving the email responses.